# Using CSS3 to animate a SVG - from a scrollable demo

Tags: jquery, css, svg, css-animations

The last requirements for this html5 banner I've made, I'm at a total loss.

Please see here: http://pepsized.com/demo/?id=665

If you scroll down the page you will see a ribbon wrapping the page and wrapping paper coming in which is exactly what I need to do for this banner I need to deliver. It's using a scroll plugin which adjusts the width of the ribbon and then animates the bow which gives the effect of wrapping it which I want to ideally use but not having to scroll as im using as a final frame on a banner.

I'm new to CSS animations and SVG. How can I use the following markup but animate within a container size of 300x250 for my final frame of this banner? I want to animate the same effect but with a keyframe.

```
<div class="ribbon">
    <div id="ribbon-left" class="ribbon" data-1500="width:0%;" data-2500="width:50%;" ></div>
    <div id="ribbon-right" class="ribbon" data-1500="width:0%;" data-2500="width:50%;" ></div>
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="337px" height="200px" >
        <path class="" style="fill:none;stroke:#49675f;stroke-width:40;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:500;stroke-dashoffset:0" data-2500="stroke-dashoffset:500;" data-4000="stroke-dashoffset:0;" d="M169,174C123,169-17.5,87.5,36,34S169,174,169,174z" />
        <path class="" style="fill:none;stroke:#49675f;stroke-width:40; stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:500;stroke-dashoffset:0" data-2500="stroke-dashoffset:500;" data-4000="stroke-dashoffset:0;"  d=" M169,174c46-5,186.5-86.5,133-140S169,174,169,174z"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ribbon {
    background:#49675f;
    height:40px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-20px;
    z-index:3;
}
#ribbon-left {
    left:0
}
#ribbon-right {
    right:0
}
.ribbon svg {
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:5; 
    left:50%; 
    top:50%; 
    margin-left:-170px; 
    margin-top:-180px
}
```

### Update

I have made adjustments to the code and done to my needs, I can work out the animation with the left right and top bottom but I need some help with the bow itself.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8j735jzw/1/

Comment: dont worry, managed to code it up and the keyframes myself and all working lovely :)

Answer (score 0):

Littile late for the party..

```
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

html

```
  <svg width="150" height="125" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <g>
    <title>Layer 1</title>
    <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#49675f" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="500" stroke-dashoffset="0" d="m78,100c-19.34616,-2.14285 -78.43605,-37.07143 -55.93563,-60s55.93563,60 55.93563,60z"/>

    <path class="path"  fill="none" stroke="#49675f" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="500" stroke-dashoffset="0" d="m80,100c16.17308,-2.75 65.57129,-47.575 46.76129,-77s-46.76129,77 -46.76129,77z"/>
   </g>

  </svg>
```

love to see your updated code and that idea is awsome..